# How to Save/Update navigation property in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, rest, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I am working on Restful API's using .Net core. Here using Entity Framework Core (code-first migration) for data related operation with SQL Server.

Here I have my main entity which is:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //...other properties.
    public IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

Where `public IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }` is reference navigation.

And `Address` is a dependent entity which looks like:

```
public class Address
{
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    //...other properties.
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

The `DbContext` is

```
public class OneToManyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    
    //..other config related connection string
}
```

The API controller for `Employee` is

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class EmployeeController : ControllerBase
{
    protected OneToManyDbContext _dbContext { get; set; }

    public EmployeeController()
    {
        _dbContext = new OneToManyDbContext();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Add(Employee employee)
    {
        _dbContext.Employees.Add(employee);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Everything works fine for CRUD related to just `Employee` entity without `Address` property. The issue is if I send the nested payload for POST method like

```
{ 
    "name":"Dennis",
    //..other properties,
    "addresses": {
                     "address1":"Place name",
                     //..other properties
                 } 
}
```

where addresses is nested key since address is belongs to Employee. Now the `Add` method fails due to it just expects `Employee` object without `Address`.

The Error message is `{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|8f31a2b1-4bcda017ebe85390.","errors":{"$.Addresses":["The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.IList'1[OneToManyRelationships.Models.Address]. Path: $.Addresses | LineNumber: 4 | BytePositionInLine: 15."]}}`

How do I fix this. Is there anything I can do like serialization/deserialization process. I am following Repository Pattern and Unit of work, just to simplify this issue I didn't put it here.

Same question is applicable to Update/Delete methods as well.

Comment: Does the input parameter  employee  have address data or null?

Comment: What is the error that throws?, posting both objects shouldnt be a problem

Comment: @Serge - I am passing the actual values. i.e.  "addresses": {
                     "address1":"Place name",
                     //..other properties
                 } as stated above. Also updated my question with error message.

Comment: @RodrigoRamírez - I updated my question with error message. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you use ajax to post data or you submit the form?

Comment: @Serge - Using third party tools like Postman, ARC..etc. Submitted data is JSON type.

Comment: ry to add [] to  adresses like this  "addresses": [{
                     "address1":"Place name",
                     //..other properties
                 },
     {
                  "address2":"Place name",
                     //..other properties
      }
     ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be a problem if you POST the employees with a list of addresses.
The problem is the way you sent your model. `IList<Addreess>` is an array of objects in JSON.
I.E : `[{},{}]` you are sending an object inside and object instead. I.E: `{{},{}}`
Following the modeling provided in the question, the JSON object sent should this:

```
{
    name: "string",
    //other values
    addresses: 
    [
        {
           "address1":"string",
           //other properties
        },
        {
           "address1":"another string"
           //some other properties
        }
    ]
}
```